# Python: Pandas Dataframe how to multiply entire column with a scalar

Tags: python, pandas, chained-assignment

How do I multiply each element of a given column of my dataframe with a scalar?
(I have tried looking on SO, but cannot seem to find the right solution)

Doing something like:

```
df['quantity'] *= -1 # trying to multiply each row's quantity column with -1
```

gives me a warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Note: If possible, I do not want to be iterating over the dataframe and do something like this...as I think any standard math operation on an entire column should be possible w/o having to write a loop:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[idx, 'quantity'] *= -1
```

**EDIT**:

I am running `0.16.2` of Pandas

full trace:

```
 SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[item] = s
```

Comment: Check type of that column using `dtype`. I can't replicate that error, it's also good to give full traceback.

Comment: I've edited to add full trace...also its not an error, its a warning (for clarity)

Comment: I think it's being caused by something other than that line, or maybe that line is causing the warning to rise that was generated from earlier. What you're getting is related to slicing the dataframe.

Comment: Curious, did you ever figure this out? I'm dealing with the same problem.

Comment: At some point before this piece of code you have filtered df to reduce the number of rows or something.  Perhaps you did `df = BigDF.query("X == 1")` or `df = BigDF[BigDF.X == 1]` or somesuch and that means df is actually just a view on BigDF.  The warning is telling you that it is forcing it to make a copy, since otherwise it would cause a change in BigDF.

Comment: So I had the same problem, my solution was make a copy of the df  `df2 = df.copy()`. Then continue your code as before using the the copy `df2['quantity'] *= -1`.  If I am doing something wrong please don't slaughter me, I am a beginner however this solution removed the warning for me. Please correct me if I am giving the incorrect solution.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here's the answer after a bit of research:

```
df.loc[:,'quantity'] *= -1 #seems to prevent SettingWithCopyWarning
```

Comment: This throws a SettingWithCopyWarning in pandas 0.18.0.

Comment: Seems outrageous how many gotchas there are in Pandas, and how much easier this is in R: `require(data.table); df[,quantity]*-1`. No need to remember colons, `.ix`,`.loc`, `iloc`, quoting field names, nor updating copies when you meant to update the original.

Comment: The real problem of why you are getting the error is not that there is anything with your code: you can use iloc, loc, or apply. 

The real problem that you have is due to how you created the df DataFrame.  Most likely you created your df as a slice of another DataFrame without using ```.copy().```  The correct way to create your df as a slice of another DataFrame is ```df = original_df.loc[some slicing].copy()```.

Comment: @Sarah is correct, almost all the answers here fail when operating on a slice of a dataframe.

Comment: @Sarah your explanation is very clear and really the error does not occur after using `copy()`. **But**, even if I modify the `df` which was made without `copy()`, the `original_df` is **not** modified. Why is that?

Comment: @starriet, Pandas does not change the original data, rather it throws the warning to let you know it *didn't* change the data: i.e. you changed a copy, rather than the original.

This is to catch chained assignment, i.e. `df["a"]["b"] = 1`, which has unpredictable results due to python's interpreter.

The [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) has a discussion on the details and reasons for this.

Comment: @MattWalck Ah, thanks! So you mean, whether or not using `copy()`, Pandas tries to copy anyway, right? But if not using `copy()` explicitly, it throws an error to tell the user _"Hey user, I think you thought the copying wouldn't happen, but in fact it does. Didn't you make a mistake?"_. Did I get you correctly?

Answer (score 88):

try using apply function.

```
df['quantity'] = df['quantity'].apply(lambda x: x*-1)
```

Comment: this is pretty graceful when compared to looping, though I still get the SettingWithCopyWarning

Comment: Series.apply is a loop and should not be used for simple multiplication. The unnecessary lambda only makes it worse.

Comment: @ALollz What alternative do you propose?

Answer (score 85):

Note: for those using pandas 0.20.3 and above, and are looking for an answer, all these options will work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((5,6)),columns=['one','two','three',
                                       'four','five','six'])
df.one *=5
df.two = df.two*5
df.three = df.three.multiply(5)
df['four'] = df['four']*5
df.loc[:, 'five'] *=5
df.iloc[:, 5] = df.iloc[:, 5]*5
```

which results in

```
   one  two  three  four  five  six
0  5.0  5.0    5.0   5.0   5.0  5.0
1  5.0  5.0    5.0   5.0   5.0  5.0
2  5.0  5.0    5.0   5.0   5.0  5.0
3  5.0  5.0    5.0   5.0   5.0  5.0
4  5.0  5.0    5.0   5.0   5.0  5.0
```

Comment: i tried this and my allocation which is running 1.2 sec now running in 0.05 sec

Comment: Also note, `df.loc[:, 'five'] *=5` would NOT work it will put it in a new row (unlike `df['four'] = df['four']*5
df.loc[:, 'five'] *=5`

Answer (score 26):

More recent pandas versions have the pd.DataFrame.multiply function.

```
df['quantity'] = df['quantity'].multiply(-1)
```

Answer (score 21):

The real problem of why you are getting the error is not that there is anything wrong with your code: you can use either `iloc`, `loc`, or `apply`, or `*=`, another of them could have worked.

The real problem that you have is due to how you created the df DataFrame.  Most likely you created your df as a slice of another DataFrame without using `.copy().`  The correct way to create your df as a slice of another DataFrame is `df = original_df.loc[some slicing].copy()`.

The problem is already stated in the error message you got " SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"
You will get the same message in the most current version of pandas too.

Whenever you receive this kind of error message, you should always check how you created your DataFrame. Chances are you forgot the `.copy()`

Comment: This should now be the accepted answer. Adding .copy() to the previous slicing operation is the key to prevent the mentioned warning.

Comment: I wasted my time with most other answers. This answer helps understand the problem clearly and provides a simple solution to the problem with .copy(). Thank you !

Answer (score 5):

Try `df['quantity'] = df['quantity'] * -1`.

Comment: this is no different than df['quantity'] *= -1 (and yes I get the same warning)

Answer (score 5):

A bit old, but I was still getting the same SettingWithCopyWarning. Here was my solution:

```
df.loc[:, 'quantity'] = df['quantity'] * -1
```

Answer (score 4):

A little late to the game, but for future searchers, this also should work:

```
df.quantity = df.quantity  * -1
```

Comment: Or `df.quantity *= -1`

Answer (score 2):

I got this warning using Pandas 0.22. You can avoid this by being *very* explicit using the [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) method:

```
df = df.assign(quantity = df.quantity.mul(-1))
```

Comment: this is the only mentioned solution that is working and doesn't throw the warning

Comment: It is not working properly for me. Besides, the answer with apply function is way simple and better. So, why do you think we should use this solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index of the column you want to apply the multiplication for

```
df.loc[:,6] *= -1
```

This will multiply the column with index 6 with -1.

Answer (score 0):

Also it's possible to use numerical indeces with `.iloc`.

```
df.iloc[:,0]  *= -1
```

Answer (score 0):

***Update 2022-08-10***

***Python: 3.10.5 - pandas: 1.4.3***

As Mentioned in Previous comments, one the applicable approaches is using ***lambda***. But, Be Careful with data types when using ***lambda*** approach.

Suppose you have a pandas Data Frame like this:

```
# Create List of lists
products = [[1010, 'Nokia', '200', 1800], [2020, 'Apple', '150', 3000], [3030, 'Samsung', '180', 2000]]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(products, columns=['ProductId', 'ProductName', 'Quantity', 'Price'])

# print DataFrame
print(df)

   ProductId ProductName Quantity  Price
0       1010       Nokia      200   1800
1       2020       Apple      150   3000
2       3030     Samsung      180   2000
```

So, if you want to triple the value of Quantity for all rows in Products and use the following Statement:

```
# This statement considers the values of Quantity as string and updates the DataFrame
df['Quantity'] = df['Quantity'].apply(lambda x:x*3)

# print DataFrame
print(df)
```

The Result will be:

```
   ProductId ProductName   Quantity  Price
0       1010       Nokia  200200200   1800
1       2020       Apple  150150150   3000
2       3030     Samsung  180180180   2000
```

The above statement considers the values of Quantity as string.

So, in order to do the multiplication in the right way, the following statement with a convert could generate correct output:

```
# This statement considers the values of Quantity as integer and updates the DataFrame
df['Quantity'] = df['Quantity'].apply(lambda x:int(x)*3)

# print DataFrame
print(df)
```

Therefore the output will be like this:

```
   ProductId ProductName  Quantity  Price
0       1010       Nokia       600   1800
1       2020       Apple       450   3000
2       3030     Samsung       540   2000
```

I Hope this could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm providing code with output:

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David', 'Emily'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 22, 35, 28],
    'Salary': [5000, 6000, 4000, 7000, 5500]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

i_want_to_multiply = 2
df['Salary'] = df['Salary'] * i_want_to_multiply

print("Updated DataFrame:")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
Updated DataFrame:
Name  Age  Salary
0    Alice   25   10000
1      Bob   30   12000
2  Charlie   22    8000
3    David   35   14000
4    Emily   28   11000
```