# Reassigning pandas column in place from a slice of another dataframe

Tags: pandas

So I learned from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46437350/3730600) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768122/python-pandas-dataframe-how-to-multiply-entire-column-with-a-scalar) that in pandas 0.20.3 and above reassigning the values of a dataframe works without giving the SettingWithCopyWarning in many ways as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((5,6)),columns=['one','two','three',
                                       'four','five','six'])
df.one *=5
df.two = df.two*5
df.three = df.three.multiply(5)
df['four'] = df['four']*5
df.loc[:, 'five'] *=5
df.iloc[:, 5] = df.iloc[:, 5]*5
```

HOWEVER

If I were to take a part of that dataframe like this for example:

```
df1 = df[(df.index>1)&(df.index<5)]
```

And then try one of the above methods for reassigning a column like so:

```
df.one *=5
```

THEN I will get the SettingWithCopyWarning.

So is this a bug or am I just missing something about the way pandas expects for this kind of operation to work?

Comment: _All_ those operations result in chained assignment if you precede it with `df1 = df[...]`. Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986/4909087) of mine might be useful.