# How do I update an entire column in a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a .xlsx file with column ['Bulb1_Cmd']

I want to multiply every item in that column by 10, update the dataframe and save as a new .xlsx file.

My current code that multiplies each value by 10 is:

```
df=pd.read_excel("bulb_data.xlsx")
s=df['Bulb1_Cmd']
for i in s.loc[:]:
    if i>0:
       ss=s.loc[:]*10
```

This will make a dataframe with the desired values, but I cannot figure out how to update the original dataframe with the new values.

I have tried

```
s.append(ss)
df.to_excel("newFile.xlsx")
```

with no luck

Comment: Please don't loop. Do this `df['Bulb1_Cmd'] = df['Bulb1_Cmd'] * 10`:

Comment: `df['Bulb1_Cmd'] *= 10`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768122/python-pandas-dataframe-how-to-multiply-entire-column-with-a-scalar

Comment: I need to use a loop for future data handling. If a value is <x and >y....

Comment: "I need to use a loop for future data handling. If a value is <x and >y." You don't *need* to use a loop for most things in pandas. This is a fundamental thing to understand. Instead use `.where()`, `.mask()` or `np.where()` to apply calculations conditionally.