# Multiply every 2nd row by -1 in pandas col

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to multiply every 2nd row by -1 but in a specified column only. Using below, I'm hoping to multiply every 2nd row in column `c` by -1.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({  
    'a' : [2.0,1.0,3.5,2.0,5.0,3.0,1.0,1.0],
    'b' : [1.0,-1.0,3.5,3.0,4.0,2.0,3.0,2.0],     
    'c' : [2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,-1.0,-1.0,-2.0,-2.0],                  
    })

df['c'] = df['c'][::2] * -1
```

Intended output:

```
     a    b    c
0  2.0  1.0  2.0
1  1.0 -1.0 -2.0
2  3.5  3.5  2.0
3  2.0  3.0 -2.0
4  5.0  4.0 -1.0
5  3.0  2.0  1.0
6  1.0  3.0 -2.0
7  1.0  2.0  2.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Pandas Dataframe how to multiply entire column with a scalar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768122/python-pandas-dataframe-how-to-multiply-entire-column-with-a-scalar)

Comment: The current top answer in this thread is a simple modification of the techniques in that thread I linked.

Comment: @Chopin - No, it is not dupe. If closed, let me know for reopen.

Comment: @blorgon, Think you're embellishing a tad.

Comment: Chopin is correct, this isn't an exact duplicate and should be left open. @blorgon: the missing part is the `[1::2]` odd-row -onlyindexing as jezrael shows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for slicing with [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for position of column `c`:

```
df.iloc[1::2, df.columns.get_loc('c')] *= -1
#working same like
#df.iloc[1::2, df.columns.get_loc('c')] = df.iloc[1::2, df.columns.get_loc('c')] * -1
```

Or use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with select values in `df.index`:

```
df.loc[df.index[1::2], 'c'] *= -1
```

Or:

```
df.loc[df.index % 2 == 1, 'c'] *= -1
```

---

```
print (df)
    
     a    b    c
0  2.0  1.0  2.0
1  1.0 -1.0 -2.0
2  3.5  3.5  2.0
3  2.0  3.0 -2.0
4  5.0  4.0 -1.0
5  3.0  2.0  1.0
6  1.0  3.0 -2.0
7  1.0  2.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 6):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.update`:

```
df.update(df['c'][1::2] * -1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     a    b    c
0  2.0  1.0  2.0
1  1.0 -1.0 -2.0
2  3.5  3.5  2.0
3  2.0  3.0 -2.0
4  5.0  4.0 -1.0
5  3.0  2.0  1.0
6  1.0  3.0 -2.0
7  1.0  2.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can write your own function:

```
def multiple(df):
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        if i // 2 == 0:
            new_row = pd.DataFrame(data = df.iloc[i]*(-1)).T      
            new_df = new_df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
        else:
            new_row = pd.DataFrame(data = df.iloc[i]).T      
            new_df = new_df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)            

        i+=1
        
    return new_df
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use divmod with a series:

```
s = 2*np.arange(len(df))%2 - 1
df["c"] = -df.c*s

     a    b    c
0  2.0  1.0  2.0
1  1.0 -1.0 -2.0
2  3.5  3.5  2.0
3  2.0  3.0 -2.0
4  5.0  4.0 -1.0
5  3.0  2.0  1.0
6  1.0  3.0 -2.0
7  1.0  2.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

```
     a    b    c
0  2.0  1.0  2.0
1  1.0 -1.0  2.0
2  3.5  3.5  2.0
3  2.0  3.0  2.0
4  5.0  4.0 -1.0
5  3.0  2.0 -1.0
6  1.0  3.0 -2.0
7  1.0  2.0 -2.0
```

```
df.loc[df.index % 2 == 1, "c" ] = df.c * - 1
```

```
     a    b    c
0  2.0  1.0  2.0
1  1.0 -1.0 -2.0
2  3.5  3.5  2.0
3  2.0  3.0 -2.0
4  5.0  4.0 -1.0
5  3.0  2.0  1.0
6  1.0  3.0 -2.0
7  1.0  2.0  2.0
```